# spring boot jbpm project load .bpmn file and start proecess

Tags: spring-boot, jbpm

Currently i am trying to Run JBPM with Spring boot with tomcat(Not jboss) using .bpmn file.
I am facing many issues. Could you please help me regarding the below points.
1- How load .BPMN file in spring boot.
2- what are the maven dependency required.
3- how start start process,human task etc.

It will be really helpful if any one able to share running code including below points
R